# Insert Element into Header

Tags: javascript, html, header

I am trying to use JavaScript to insert new elements in my HTML file.

My HTML file looks like this

```
<header>
</header>
<section>
</section>
<main>
  <p id="time"></p>
</main>
<footer>
</footer>
<script src="first.js">
</script>
```

I have been inserting elements for now just in the body tag, by using

```
var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
var content = document.createTextNode('text');
h1.appendChild(content);
document.body.appendChild(h1);
```

When JavaScript inserts the elements, it just puts them at the bottom of the HTML file,

```
<footer>
</footer>
<script src="first.js">
</script>
<h1>text</h1>
```

I want to know how to insert elements directly into my the HEADER tags WITHOUT using id's or other div's.

```
<header></header>
```

Like this

```
<header>
  <h1>text</h1>
</header>
<section>
</section>
<main>
  <p id="time"></p>
</main>
<footer>
</footer>
<script src="first.js">
</script>
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].appendChild(h1);`

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9wcjyn5j/)**

You may also try something like this:

```
// Get all headers
var headers = document.getElementsByTagName('header');

headers[0].appendChild(h1); // inserts into first header
headers[1].appendChild(h1); // inserts into second header
// And so on...
```

Also you can loop. Alternatively [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is another option.